# Laravel groupBy value and store the sum of another value with the groupBy value as the key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Sorry for the long-winded title, I'm just not sure how to precisely word what I'm trying to do.

So I have a table of flights like this.

```
id | user_id | orig | dest | value    |
=======================================
1  |    1    | LHR  | WLG  | 34000.00 |
2  |    1    | LHR  | WLG  | 47000.00 |
3  |    1    | LHR  | AKL  | 22000.00 |
```

What I want is an array of destinations (`'dest'`) with the sum of the value of any record with that destination.

I'm currently using Eloquent to pull retrieve the records then groupBy on `'dest'`

```
$transactions =  AirTran::select('orig','dest','value')->where('user_id','1')->get();

$group_tran = $transactions->groupBy('dest');
```

Unfortunately this returns each row seperately in the array instead of a sum of the value:

```
WLG:
    0:
       orig: 'LHR'
       dest: 'WLG'
       value: '34000.00'
    1:
       orig: 'LHR'
       dest: 'WLG'
       value: '47000.00'
AKL:
    0:
       orig: 'LHR'
       dest: 'AKL'
       value: '22000.00'
```

But what I actually want is this:

```
WLG:
    0:
       orig: 'LHR'
       dest: 'WLG'
       value: '81000.00'
AKL:
    0:
       orig: 'LHR'
       dest: 'AKL'
       value: '22000.00'
```

Is there a way to get a sum of the `'value'` column using Eloquent rather than using PHP as I am below:

```
foreach($transactions as $transaction) {

   if(isset($data[$transaction->dest]['revenue'])){
       $data[$transaction->dest]['revenue'] += $transaction->value;
    } else {
       $data[$transaction->dest]['revenue'] = $transaction->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: There can be multiple `orig` values per `dest`. Which one do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function sum of eloquant.
Your code can be like :

$transactions =  AirTran::select('orig','dest','value')->where('user_id','1')->get();

$group_tran = $transactions->groupBy('dest')
                             ->sum('value');

or directly with one command:

```
$group_tran= AirTran::select('orig','dest','value')->where('user_id','1')
                       ->sum('value')
                       ->groupBy('dest')
                       ->where('user_id','1')
                       ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

When I try to use sum() I am getting a response of 0. Could this be because values are inside another array indexed with a number?